# Unwanted whitespace above li element

Tags: html, css, html-lists, whitespace

There is whitespace above each li element and I can't figure out what is causing it. I've tried playing with margins and padding but nothing seems to do the trick. I want the top of each column to align.

Here is a picture of what is happening. I want the top of each column to align. [image: White space is causing the columns to become uneven]

Here is a link to the page [link](http://podmtg.com/episodes.html)

```
#episodes {
    width: 100%;
    background: #ffffff;
    padding-top: 200px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}

.episode img {
    width: 100%;
}

.episode {
    width: 300px;
    position: relative;
}

#episodes ul{
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    font-size: 0;
}

#episodes li {
    width: 300px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 10px;
}


.caption {
    height: 500px;
    background: #e6e6e6;
}

.caption h1 {
    width: 100%;
    font-family: futura-pt, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #061838;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding: 10px;

}

.caption p {
    font-family: museo-slab, serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 12px;
    hyphens: none;
    margin-top: 0;
    padding: 10px;
}

.date {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: It is because of the different height by the text elements. Since these are not set on something fixed, it is calculated from the actual text. Check by adding more text in the smaller boxes.

Comment: FWIW, you should not have more than one `h1` per page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try below code, it should work for you

```
#episodes ul {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}

#episodes li {
    float: left;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm.